# Running into a number format exception when i'm trying to use the BufferedReader to store integer inputs into an array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, input, bufferedreader

I am trying to use the BufferedReader to take in up to 100 inputs until the integer 1 is entered where the program then terminates.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
        //Instantiating an array of size 100, the max size.

        int arrayOfInputs [] = new int[100];

        //Creating the reader. 

        System.out.println("Enter some inputs");
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        //Putting the inputs into a string.

        String stringOfInputs = BR.readLine();

        //Splitting the strings

        String [] sOI = BR.readLine().split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < sOI.length; i++)
        {
            //parsing the split strings into integers

            if (Integer.parseInt(sOI[i]) != 0)
            {
                arrayOfInputs[i] = Integer.parseInt(sOI[i]);
                System.out.print(arrayOfInputs[i] + " ");
            }
        }
}
```

I do not understand why my program is not working. I am reading the input, storing it into a string, splitting the string, and then converting the split parts into integers to then store into my array of size 100. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some sample input that causes it to fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am reading the input, storing it into a string, splitting the string, and then converting the split parts into integers to then store into my array of size 100.

You're calling `BufferedReader#readLine()` twice. The first line is ignored and only the second line is processed. You should use the variable that saves the first read line:

```
String stringOfInputs = BR.readLine();  // TODO rename variable to use lowercase, e.g. br

//Splitting the strings

String [] sOI = stringOfInputs.split(" ");
...
```